# The Archimedean Principle | Proof by Contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, integers, natural-numbers

I am a first-semester BSc. Engineering student and I have been studying the **Archimedean Principle** as part of my coursework. Recently, I came across Jay Cummings' proof for this principle in his book '***Real Analysis - A Long Form Mathematics Textbook***'. While studying the proof, I encountered a difficulty and would appreciate some clarification.

The Archimedean Principle states that,

> ***'Iff **a** and **b** are real numbers with **a > 0**, then there exists**
> **a natural number **n** such that **na > b**.'***

In '*Real Analysis*'; the author proves the Archimedean Principle using a **proof by *contradiction***.

A summarized version of his proof is as follows:

> *Since $a, b \in \mathbb R;$ then, $a/ b \in \mathbb R$,
>
> Let $x = a/ b ,(x \in \mathbb R)$,
>
> Assume*
> *for contradiction, that $x$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.*

The author is attempting to prove that,
**Statement**: $(\forall x \in \mathbb R)$, $(\exists n \in \mathbb Z)$, such that $n> x$. (For any real number $x$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n> x$.)

> *Since $\mathbb N \in \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$*
> *is complete, $sup(\mathbb N)$ exists.
>
> Let $sup(\mathbb N)= \alpha$,
>
> Then, $\alpha - 1$ is*
> *not an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.
>
> That is, $\exists m \in (\mathbb Z,\mathbb N)$ such that, $m> \alpha -1$.
>
> Consequently, $m+ 1> \alpha$.*
>
> *#Contradiction $(sup(\mathbb N)= \alpha$. But also, $m+ 1> \alpha$ and $(m+ 1)\in \mathbb N)$*
>
> *Therefore, we can conclude that $x$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.
>
> By substituting $b/ a$ for $x$ in **Statement** we get,
>
> $\forall b/ a \in \mathbb R$; $\exists n \in \mathbb Z$, such that $n> b/ a$.
>
> Therefore it follows that, $\exists n \in \mathbb N$, such that **na> b**. (*There exists a natural number **n**, such that **na> b***.*)

However, I have a question regarding the proof.

Since we are considering the set $\mathbb N$, where the last element is $sup(\mathbb N)$ and the element before that is $sup(\mathbb N) - 1$ all the numbers between these two are decimals and are not included in $\mathbb N$. On the other hand, $m$ belongs to $\mathbb N$, so $m \le sup(\mathbb N)$. Therefore, how can there exist an integer $m$ such that, $m> sup(\mathbb N)- 1$?

Doesn't this imply that **there exists an integer $ m$; such that, $sup(\mathbb N)- 1< m \le sup(\mathbb N)$, while $sup(\mathbb N)- 1$ and $sup(\mathbb N)$ are the two closest integers**?

> $\mathbb N$ = {$1, 2, 3, \dots, sup(\mathbb N)- 2, sup(\mathbb N)- 1, sup(\mathbb N)$}

Comment: $\Bbb N$ is not an element of $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb N$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Doesn't this imply that there exists an integer $ m$; such that, $sup(\mathbb N)- 1< m \le sup(\mathbb N)$, while $sup(\mathbb N)- 1$ and $sup(\mathbb N)$ are the two closest integers?"*

Yes, in fact, since $\alpha-1$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$ it means that there exists at least one number from $\mathbb{N}$ that is larger than it, let it be $m$ like shown in the proof. As you said $m\le \sup{(\mathbb{N})},m\in \mathbb N$ and this means that $m=\sup{(\mathbb N)}$.

I hope you understand the rest of the proof from here.